# Help please with an animation of a cardboard chocolate package from a dieline

Tags: modeling, animation

I wonder if anyone can help me?  I'm new to blender and have managed to almost create the package and animate it folding from a flat dieline into a box.  However, in real life, the final shape isn't a straight box, there are additional folds in the side which create the box to slope at the top when it's folded up, and I have no idea how to make this happen in blender.

I've included the blender file as is,  and a photo of what I'm trying to create.  If anyone could give me a pointer I'd be super grateful.

Best wishes,  Jason

[image: folding animation]

Reference image:
[image: reference image]

blender file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Lvgzm7NQUCQcS7niRhJe0vTo7uC1Efh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should try something like that:

- First merge by distance as it seems like you have overlapping vertices
- You need to divide your sides like that in order to be able to fold them:

[image]

- Then lower down the chain of bones in order to put the rotation axis at the bottom, and create 3 bones that you make children of the bottom bone in order to control the top vertices and make the fold fold:

[image]

- Frame 0:

[image]

- Frame 80:

[image]

Comment: Hi moonboots, and thanks for helping.  The issue is that as paper isn't stretchy, if i create this and rotate the middle vertical bone, it just stretches the paper, what should happen is that it the left and right bone would somehow have to move to accomodate this rotation. I'm really lost i'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, it may not be as simple as my solution but I think it's a way to do it, see my edit, I hope it's more clear

Comment: If anyone could help and create a blender file I'd be happy to pay for their time.