How to convert Illustrator file (Packaging design with dieline) into 3d model in Blender
Totally new to Blender and try to do my first 3d model. I have an artwork(a box with graphic) I did in Illustrator with dieline. What is the best correct method to make that 2D art into 3D model?
I have seen people export a png file from Illustration, import that png file into Blender, slice the box into pieces then create the dieline in Blender, add thickness on the cardboard, then fold the box.
Is there another easier way to make the 3d box? Trying to avoid to create the die cut in Blender. I tried export the art from Illustrator to SVG file. (graphics with dieline), but what I see after I import the SVG file is all grey box.
I would like to know the options with fastest and best result if it exists? Thank you for all your help in advanced!

My experience is Adobe Dimension and it's very limited to what it can do done.


Can you please clarify what your Illustrator graphic looks like? Did you create an unwrapped box, e.g. as seen at 4:39 here?

@Phrogz, yes similar to your example posted but mine is not only vector art, it also has some real product photos on it. Also, I did created the unwrapped box with dieline on top.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218155/how-to-make-animation-of-a-cardboard-chocolate-package-from-a-dieline https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31621/folding-a-cube-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239430/armature-to-unfold-a-chinese-food-box-to-a-flat-page/239538#239538 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191418/how-to-model-a-burger-package-with-beveled-edges https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210073/how-to-parent-bones-to-the-panels-of-a-dieline-package-paper-folding https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238065/bevel-modifier

You don’t want to fold the box, you just want to wrap an unfolded image on 6 sides of a box?

@Phrogz, you are correct, I don't need the animation. I just need to create the 3d model from a flat 2d artwork.

There must be 100 tutorials on this, but I'm too lazy to look them up and I need to practice these skills. Assuming you have an image with six rectangular pieces:


Create a box in Blender Add > Mesh > Cube

Scale the cube to have the dimensions or aspect ratio you want

Create a new material for your cube

Set the material to use an Image Texture for the Base Color, and open your image

Go into the UV Editing tab at top; your box might already be unwrapped close to how you want!


If it's close, just adjust the layout of the faces in the UV Editor to match your image map.
If it's not close, unwrap it yourself:

Think about which edges on your box need to be cut with scissors to lay the box out like your image; select each (2 to enter edge mode, click on an edge) and mark it as seam (UV > Mark Seam).

after you've marked all the edges as seams, select all and use UV > Unwrap.
If the Unwrap didn't work perfectly, move vertices and edges in the UV editor to match your object.





I was originally unable to upload images to this post, so I made a quick video recording my quick-and-dirty attempt to demonstrate the above. I tried not to use any keyboard shortcuts, but they make your life so much easier.

thank you so much for the instruction! So, this concept is very similar to how I did the 3d model in Adobe Dimension. What if I have a more complicate dieline, for example, a caddy case? What is the best way to create a caddy in Blender?

@VincentChan You would model it, then texture it. But that’s kind of a different question. If you feel that my answer fully solved your question, please tick the checkmark to accept it.

My works usually have the CAD dieline. I think I need to create the model first. My question was how should I start with the process? I have seen people import the png file with dieline, then build the dieline in Blender and fold the package. Another way I see people import dxf file of the dieline, then wrap the dieline with the packaging graphics. Seems there are different methods to create 3d packaging. What is the right way to do it? Thanks!
